# Angularjs How to manage Code

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angularjs. I have a page like this.

[image]

I have a single controller which does all the work which is currently working fine. I want to manage my code to use angular-given-functionalities by using filters, services, controllers etc.

In this page i have many sections i am mentioning here.

1. Search filters
2. Category
3. Attributes
4. Tags
5. Pagination Section plus Grid or List links
6. Sort plus Compare section
7. Product data to display

How can i break my code in separate chunks to manage it properly.

I have created a service which does all ajax related work.
Here is the dependency.

```
1. Search does nothing except page redirect
2. Category can have a view more which will update itself will more then 10 records
3. Attributes can have viewmore button to display more then 10 attributes. Attribute can also impect on the following
        When we select single on multiple attribute it will change
        1. Category
        2. Attributes
        3. Tags
        4. Pagination
        5. Listing (Product data to display)
4. Tags can be removed and can have excatly same behavior as Attributes
5. Pagination will change itself and product data display
6. Sort will have same as pagination
7. Nothing
```

I dont need code just some suggestions on how can i choose things from Angular to make managed code.

Comment: The question implies that you need a qualified person who will design full-blown app from the scratch for you.

Comment: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide ; But to me, It's primeraly opinion based